# Conditions for cyclic behaviour of ARIMA model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I'm trying to model and forecast a time series that is [cyclic rather than seasonal](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cyclicts/) (i.e. there are seasonal-like patterns, but not with a fixed period). This should be possible to do using an ARIMA model, as mentioned in Section 8.5 of [Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/5):

> The value of $p$ is important if the data show cycles. To obtain cyclic forecasts, it is necessary to have $p\geq 2$ along with some additional conditions on the parameters. For an AR(2) model, cyclic behaviour occurs if $\phi^2_1+4\phi_2<0$.

What are these *additional conditions on the parameters* in the general ARIMA(p,d,q) case? I haven't been able to find them anywhere.

Comment: Have you looked into complex roots of the polynomial $\phi(B)$ at all? It seems like this may be what the quotation is referring to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Some graphical intuition

In [AR models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), cyclic behavior come from complex conjugate roots to the characteristic polynomial. To first give intuition, I've plotted the impulse response functions below to two example AR(2) models.

1. A persistent process with complex roots.
2. A persistent process with real roots.

[image]
[image]

For $j=1\,\ldots, p$, Roots of the characteristic polynomial are $\frac{1}{\lambda_j}$ where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p$ are eigenvalues of the $A$ matrix I define below . With a complex conjugate eigenvalues $\lambda = r e^{i \omega t}$ and $\bar{\lambda}= r e^{-i \omega t} $, the $r$ controls the damping (where $r \in [0, 1)$) and $\omega$ controls the frequency of the cosine wave.

### Detailed AR(2) example

Let's assume we have the AR(2):

$$ y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \phi_2 y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$$

[You can write any AR(p) as a VAR(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73378/reciprocal-roots-and-eigenvalues-relationship-in-time-series). In this case, the VAR(1) representation is:

$$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} y_t \\ y_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} }_{X_t} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} \phi_1 & \phi_2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{A}  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} y_{t-1} \\ y_{t-2} \end{bmatrix}}_{X_{t-1}} + \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_t \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{U_t}$$
Matrix $A$ governs the dynamics of $X_t$ and hence $y_t$. The characteristic equation of matrix $A$ is:
$$ \lambda^2 - \phi_1 \lambda - \phi_2 = 0$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are:
$$ \lambda_1 = \frac{\phi_1 + \sqrt{\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2}}{2} \quad \quad \lambda_2 =  \frac{\phi_1 - \sqrt{\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2}}{2} $$
The eigenvectors of $A$ are:
$$ \mathbf{v}_1 = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \quad \mathbf{v}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Note that $\operatorname{E}[X_{t+k} \mid X_t, X_{t-1}, \ldots] = A^kX_t$. Forming the eigenvalue decomposition and raising $A$ to the $k$th power.
$$A^k = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^k & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^k \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}  & \frac{-\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}\\ \frac{-1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}& \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2} \end{bmatrix} $$

A real eigenvalue $\lambda$ leads to decay as you raise $\lambda^k$. Eigenvalues with non-zero imaginary components leads to cyclic behavior.

#### Eigenvalues with imaginary component case: $\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2 < 0$

In the AR(2) context, we have complex eigenvalues if $\phi_1^2 + 4\phi_2 < 0$. Since $A$ is real, they must come in pairs that are [complex conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) of each other.

Following Chapter 2 of Prado and West (2010), let 
$$ c_t = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - \bar{\lambda}} y_t - \frac{\lambda \bar{\lambda}}{\lambda - \bar{\lambda}} y_{t-1}$$

You can show the forecast $\operatorname{E}[y_{t+k} \mid y_t, y_{t-1}, \ldots]$ is given by:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}[y_{t+k} \mid y_t, y_{t-1}, \ldots] &= c_t \lambda ^k + \bar{c}_t \bar{\lambda}^k \\
&= a_t r^k \cos(\omega k + \theta_t)
\end{align*}

Speaking loosely, adding the complex conjugates cancels out their imaginary component leaving you with a single damped cosine wave in the space of real numbers. (Note we must have $0 \leq r < 1$ for stationarity.)

If you want to find $r$, $\omega$, $a_t$, $\theta_t$, start by using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) that $re^{i \theta} = r \cos \theta + r \sin \theta$, we can write:

$$ \lambda = re^{i\omega} \quad \bar{\lambda} = re^{-i\omega} \quad r = |\lambda| = \sqrt{ -\phi_2}$$
$$\omega = \operatorname{atan2}\left( \operatorname{imag} \lambda, \operatorname{real} \lambda \right) = \operatorname{atan2}\left( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\phi_1^2-4\phi_2}, \frac{1}{2} \phi_1\right) $$

$$ a_t = 2 |c_t| \quad \quad \theta_t = \operatorname{atan2}\left( \operatorname{imag} c_t, \operatorname{real} c_t \right) $$

## Appendix

#### Note *Confusing terminology warning!* Relating the characteristic polynomial of A to characteristic polynomial of AR(p)

Another time-series trick is to use the [lag operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator) to write the AR(p) as:

$$ \left(1 - \phi_1 L - \phi_2L^2 - \ldots - \phi_pL^p \right)y_t = \epsilon_t$$

Replace lag operator $L$ with some variable $z$ and people often refer to $1 - \phi_1 z  - \ldots - \phi_pz^p$ as the characteristic polynomial of the AR(p) model.  As [this answer discusses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73378/reciprocal-roots-and-eigenvalues-relationship-in-time-series), this is exactly the characteristic polynomial of $A$ where $z = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. The roots $z$ are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues. (Note: for the model to be stationary you want $|\lambda| < 1$, that is inside the unit cirlce, or equivalently $|z|>1$, that is outside the unit circle.)

### References

Prado, Raquel and Mike West, *Time Series: Modeling, Computation, and Inference*, 2010

Comment: I am surprised I am the only up vote at the moment. Good answer!

Comment: @Taylor It's an old, inactive question. :)