# Expressibility of VAR(1) models

Tags: time-series, arima, modeling, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

Am I correct in understanding that vector autoregressive (VAR) models of order one can capture seemingly more general modeling frameworks such as VAR(p) models, for orders $p > 1$, and ARMA models?

For instance, the VAR(p) model $$x_t = A_1 x_{t-1} + A_2 x_{t-2} + \cdots + A_p x_{t-p} + \epsilon_t$$ can be re-written as the VAR(1) model $$\begin{bmatrix} x_t \\ x_{t-1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{t-p+1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_p \\
I & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  &   & \ddots &   \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & I \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{t-1} \\ x_{t-2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{t-p}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_t \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Additionally, the ARMA(p,q) model $$x_t = A_1 x_{t-1} + A_2 x_{t-2} + \cdots + A_p x_{t-p} + \epsilon_t + B_1\epsilon_{t-1} + B_2\epsilon_{t-2} + \cdots + B_q\epsilon_{t-q}$$ can be re-written as the VAR(1) model $$\begin{bmatrix} x_t \\ x_{t-1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{t-p+1} \\ \epsilon_{t} \\ \epsilon_{t-1} \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_{t-q+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & A_2 & \cdots & A_p & B_1 & B_2 & \cdots & B_q \\
I & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  &   & \ddots & &  & & \ddots &   \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & I & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  &   & \ddots & &  & & \ddots &   \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{t-1} \\ x_{t-2} \\ \vdots \\ x_{t-p} \\ \epsilon_{t-1} \\ \epsilon_{t-2} \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_{t-q}
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
\omega_{t,1} \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \omega_{t,1} \\ \omega_{t,2} \\ \vdots \\ \omega_{t,q}
\end{bmatrix}, $$
where $\omega_{t,1}, \cdots, \omega_{t,q} \sim P$ are i.i.d. ($P$ is the probability distribution of the errors $\epsilon_t$).

This is primarily of theoretical interest to me, but is there any (practical) disadvantage to writing VAR(p) and ARMA models in such a form?

Comment: It's much more natural to handle the recursive nature of auto-regressive models when writing it is an 1st order model. The recursion then is largely raising that big matrix you wrote to higher powers, and the eigenvalues of that matrix are very important. For example, see this answer of mine: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338473/conditions-for-cyclic-behaviour-of-arima-model/389648#389648